# retrieving all objects in an array JS

Tags: javascript, dynamic-arrays, servicenow

I'm working in ServiceNow and trying to set up an array that retrieves all of the knowledge articles relevant to a user.  My code below is only returning one of the articles and I'm not sure why...any suggestions?

```
var kaArray = [];
var ka = new GlideRecord('my_knowledge');
ka.addQuery('workflow_state', 'Published');
ka.addQuery('kb_category.label', 'Benefits');
ka.addQuery('occ_series', 'CONTAINS', occ)
  .addOrCondition('location', 'CONTAINS', loc)
  .addOrCondition(
    ka.addNullQuery('location') && ka.addNullQuery('occ_series')
  );    
ka.orderByDesc('sys_updated_on');
ka.query();
while(ka.next()) {
    obj = {number: ka.number.toString(),
           short_desc: ka.short_description.toString(),
           url: 'kb_view.do?sysparm_article=' + ka.number}; 
    kaArray.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: We're going to need more information about the records in question and why you think some are missing.

Comment: Wait.. what's going on with this "&&"? You can't use javascript conditional operators when building query conditions.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're going for. The first 2 conditions in that OR block are matching the two variables (respectively), but you want to include rows which are empty for BOTH `location` and `federal_occ_series`. What you really want is an "über-OR", but I don't know how to do it with a GlideRecord script. Are you able to build your condition in a normal list using the Condition Builder? If so, right-click the filter breadcrumbs (blue text) and select "Copy Encoded Query", then try using *just that* in a call to ka.addEncodedQuery(<copied encoded query>);

Comment: Thanks Joey!  I did that and it works out.  One thing I noticed was that my addEncodedQuery had to come before my addQuery or else it looks like the code ignores my addQuery...have you come across something like this?  Does order count?

Comment: Typically, you just do EITHER `addEncodedQuery()` OR `addQuery()`. You just put everything you need on the encoded query, in place of all the `addQuery` calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that I'd recommend, one of which is probably the solution to your problem.

1. You're using "&&", a conditional operator, to.. well I'm afraid I'm not totally sure. You cannot do this in JavaScript in the way you're attempting to. Also, Since `.addOrCondition()` does not return a value that you would want to use as a bool), this won't work. Instead, just put the next command on the next line. I'll show you a finished version of your code at the bottom.
2. Instead of these complicated sequences of `.addNullQuery()`, `addQuery()`, and .addOrCondition() calls, simply navigate to the table you're interested in filtering, and literally build the filter there in the condition builder. Then, right-click the **final** filter breadcrumb, and click "copy query", then use `.addEncodedQuery()`. Like so:

[image: copy query]
    gr.addEncodedQuery('short_descriptionLIKEeclipse^kb_category=c78a2d2047b002007f47563dbb9a71bf^workflow_state=published' /*The result of clicking "copy query"*/);

3. Why are you using a scoped app and custom table? The scoped app makes sense if you're planning to list it on the market, but based on the table name, it sounds like it's for a specific business. I recommend a global app, if anything. I also very strongly recommend, whether scoped or global, that you simply create a new knowledgebase rather than creating a whole new table, unless you had some advanced functionality you'll need on this KB and are willing to sacrifice a great deal of OOB functionality to get it. Not saying what you're doing is wrong, just want to make sure you're aware of the hassle you might be creating for yourself down the line. :-)
4. From what I can see, you don't, with your CURRENT configuration, have to worry about JavaScript's pass-by-reference idiosyncrasies, I don't see you declare "obj" anywhere. You might want to do that, and give it a better name. You might want to funtionalize your addition of that object to the array though. If #5 isn't right, then the problem is most likely due to a pass-by-ref issue that I missed, at least that's my guess. I can see that you've got at least one pass-by-ref issue on the third line inside your while loop:

   url: 'kb_view.do?sysparm_article=' + ka.number};

**Always** use "getters and setters". That is to say, when you want a value from a GlideRecord, never directly reference `gr.fieldName`. Instead, use `gr.getValue('fieldName');`. As one alternative (which I don't like but have no rational reason not to) you can also use `.toString()`, as you have in a few other places. This explicitly casts the value to a string rather than the Object that it is (a GlideElement object). I don't really like this because it means that you're force-casting an OBJECT to a STRING. There is no EASY path to doing that, so it relies on a built-in method of the GlideElement class to override the .toString method of most other types.

5. I'm betting that this query, the way it's written anyway, is returning only one record. You can easily test this by using something like `gs.info('Looking through ' + ka.getRowCount() + ' records.');` after the query.

For you, I humbly recommend "[Learning ServiceNow](https://smile.amazon.com/Learning-ServiceNow-Tim-Woodruff/dp/1785883321)". Full disclosure, this is my own book. That said, I've tailored this book **specifically** for people who are at EXACTLY your level of knowledge and experience, and I think that you would get a lot out of it. Most SN devs would get a lot out of it, but I think you are in a particular position to get the most out of it. 
I know it says June 9th, but this should be releasing by the end of this month or within a few days of there.

Here's a version of what I think you're trying to do, that ought to work. I'm sure that the query will need a little tweaking - I had to kind of guess at what you were going for, but I think the use of ^NQ is closest to what you were looking to accomplish. Like I said, just build your query on the table, then copy it into encQuery (and replace my existing logic/return your proper query from buildEncQuery). 
Here it is:

```
 /**
 * encQuery will hold the temporary and final encoded query strings, which will look something like this (when finished):
 * "workflow_state=published^kb_category.label=Benefits^federal_occ_seriesLIKEOCC_HERE^ORlocationLIKELOC_HERE^NQworkflow_state=published^kb_category.label=Benefits^locationISEMPTY^federal_occ_seriesISEMPTY"
 * @type {String}
 */
var encQuery = buildEncQuery(occ, loc); //occ and loc were used in your original queries, so I assume they're variables that are available to you in this scope at this point in your script. 
/**
 * An array of objects, each containing data about knowledge articles returned from our query using encQuery.
 * @type {{name: string, short_desc: string, url: string}[]}
 */
var knowledgeArray = [];
/**
 * The GR we're iterating over
 * @type {GlideRecord}
 */
var knowledgeGR = new GlideRecord('x_81991_federal_hc_federal_knowledge');
knowledgeGR.addEncodedQuery(encQuery);
knowledgeGR.orderByDesc('sys_updated_on');
knowledgeGR.query();
while (knowledgeGR.next()) {
    knowledgeArray.push({
                     number:     knowledgeGR.getValue('number'),
                     short_desc: knowledgeGR.getValue('short_description'),
                     url:        'kb_view.do?sysparm_article=' + knowledgeGR.getValue('number')
                 });
}
gs.info('Located ' + knowledgeGR.getRowCount() + ' records. Array length: ' + knowledgeArray.length + '.');
//Done

/**
 * Builds the encoded query for the calling function.
 * @param occ {*}
 * @param loc {*}
 * @returns {string}
 */
function buildEncQuery(occ, loc) {
    if (occ === undefined || loc === undefined) {
        return;
    }
    var encQuery = 'workflow_state=published^kb_category.label=Benefits'
    encQuery += '^federal_occ_seriesLIKE' + occ + '^ORlocationLIKE' + loc + '^NQ' + encQuery + '^locationISEMPTY^federal_occ_seriesISEMPTY';
    return encQuery;
}
```

EDIT: I notice you're posting in StackOverflow a lot. However, you don't seem to be marking your questions as answered once they are. I recommend that you do that, but I also recommend that you check out [sndevs.slack.com](http://sndevs.slack.com). It's a great community of other ServiceNow developers.

Comment: Tim, this is the most thorough answer I've ever received, thanks so much for spending the time typing all this out!  For #3, our team did create a new KB, but there were some fields we wanted to add to the KA forms.  We basically extended kb_knowledge and added the fields we needed & now we're querying that table.  How did you know my query would only return one result?  I am trying to fully understand your many suggestions above, will let you know if this works.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Dave - I don't know for sure that your query will only return one result, but I assume that it will since it... seems to be, based on your post. :-P

Comment: Tim, thanks for your help above, I finally got the query to return all of the relevant articles.  Do you have any resources on how to then create a table dynamically from this array?  I would like the table to have number, description, and link as columns.  After some reading, I'm pretty sure I have to use ng-repeat, but am completely new to this.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is the documentation on ng-repeat:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat - You will need to learn Angular in order to understand how to make these things work.